# How to add first and last classes to local task items?

Tags: 7, theming

I'd like to add some classes to local task items, now there is only "active" class available which is pretty not flexible, I'd like to have "first" on first item and "last" on last item.

Tried `theme_menu_local_tasks()` and `theme_menu_local_task()`, neither of them work. And the post about "[Add first and last classes to secondary local tasks](http://adaptivethemes.com/add-first-and-last-classes-to-secondary-local-tasks)" is probably for Drupal 6 so it's not working either.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery :first and :last selectors, example:

```
$('ul li:first').addClass(‘first’);
$('ul li:last’).addClass(‘last’);
```

Or you can use CSS :first-child and :last-child selectors, example:

```
li:first-child { add your css here }
li:last-child { add your css here }
```

The CSS way will give better performance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [hook_menu_local_tasks_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu_local_tasks_alter/7). You can access all local tasks through the first parameter`$data` and you can add more class names to the option array `localized_options` of each tab.

```
function YOURMODULE_menu_local_tasks_alter(&$data, $router_item, $root_path){
    if(isset($data['tabs'][0])){
        $tabs =  $data['tabs'][0];  
        $i = 1; 
        foreach($tabs['output'] as &$t){
            if($i == 1) $class = 'first';
            elseif($i = $tabs['count']) $class = 'last';
            if(isset($t['#link']['localized_options']['attributes'])){
                $attributes = $t['#link']['localized_options']['attributes'];
                $attributes['class'][] = $class;
            }else{
                $attributes = array(
                    'attributes' => array(
                        'class' => array($class)
                    )
                );
            }
            $t['#link']['localized_options'] = $attributes; 
            $i++;
        }
        $data['tabs'][0] = $tabs;
    }
}
```

If you don't want to loop through all local tasks for performance sake, you can directly update`$data['tabs'][0]['output'][0]` and `$data['tabs'][0]['output'][$data['tabs'][0]['count']-1]`. But you should check if the indexes exist, otherwise you will get **Warning: Undefined index...**

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `nth-child` CSS 3 property if `.active` is not convinent:

```
p:nth-child(2) {
  background:#ff0000;
}
```

Source is [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child).